# Freezing Python app with py2exe with custom modules

Tags: python, module, py2exe, setup.py

I am using py2exe to create an executable from my python project.

My file structure is as follows:

```
Conda_env_38\
    app\
        __init__.py
        GUI.py
        wave_class.py
    tests\
        __init__.py
    README
    setup.py
```

GUI.py is the main app that uses tkinter.

wave_class.py is used by GUI.py for some calculations
tests is for future growth and not used right now.

setup.py contains the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup (
    name='GUI Data Viewer',
    description="digital Data Visualizer app",
    version="0.1",
    packages=['app'],
    windows=['app\GUI.py'],
    options={ 'py2exe': {
        'packages': None,
        'includes': None}
    },
)
```

**init**.py contains:

```
__all__ = ['GUI', 'wave_class']
import wave_class
```

In my console, I cd to this directory, and run:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

The script runs successfully and I get my exe in the new 'dist' folder. But when I run it, it generates a log file that contains the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "GUI.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wave_class'
```

**So why wasn't wave_class included in 'app'? How do I get py2exe to include wave_class.py?**

btw, this runs perfectly from my IDE, so it's not a missing import in GUI.py

Comment: your file __init__.py in the folder app is empty?

Comment: __init__.py contains the following: 
    __all__ = ['GUI', 'wave_class']
    import wave_class